# Exit completely from a recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, unity-game-engine, while-loop

I have a question regarding a recursive function I made. Is there a way I can completely exit a funcion once I get to the "return arraydenodes" line? Because I followed the code execution with visual studio and once the execution gets to the above mentioned line, it returns to the stack (or so I believe) right into the "else" from the while loop. And because of that, the `path.Add` lines keeps executing, giving me a different result. Here's the code.

```
private Node[] checkTheOtherDude(Node start, Node endpadre, Node end, Node previousNodeTemp)
{

    //Debug.Log(previousNode);
    while(endpadre != null && !stop)
    {

        if (!Physics.Linecast(end.transform.position, endpadre.transform.position)) // end y endpadre se ven?
        {
            previousNode = endpadre;
            Node newParent = endpadre.padre;

            checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, end, previousNode); // chequear n y n padre padre

        }
        else
        {
            //previousNode = endpadre;
            path.Add(end);
            path.Add(previousNode);
            end = endpadre;
            Node newParent = end.padre;
            checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, endpadre, previousNode);
        }
    }       
        stop = true;
        path.Add(end);
        path.Add(start);
        path.Reverse();
        arraydeNodes = path.ToArray();
        return arraydeNodes;                  
}
```

It seems that I have solved the issue, the problem (or at least I think) it was the while condition, changed it to `while (endpadre != null && !stop && endpadre != start)` I was missing the `endpadre != start` so that the loop would end right when the end node was the same as the start node.

Comment: If you design it correctly, it shouldn't matter.  If you're running into trouble, your recursive method is doing too much (separation of concerns) or isn't structured properly.  When the inner-most call exits, it should naturally return all the way up the stack i.e. within the proper return structure of the method.

Comment: when you have recursion exit at the end of method, you will not exit until each recursive call reaches it's exit point. Which means traversing everything. Consider to put exit condition at the beginning of recursive method

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what the function is supposed to do, this could be wrong for this specific case, but generally you want to `return` the results of recursive calls.

Comment: First I'm not sure why you need to return Node[].  It is in the parameter list so it will get update automatically.  Once you can eliminate Node[] as a return value you can return a Boolean stop to get back up to the top.  I disagree with Rory answer because I've written lots of recursive code and in some cases you need to return a variable to stop processing.

Comment: Is it ok that code that goes after the while loop will be executed multiple times (as many as your recursion level)? Also `path.Reverse();` will be called multiple times, which is something I am not sure you really want

Comment: @jdweng It returns a Node[] because it's a Laze Theta code, and the original A* code needs an array of nodes for a path. The funny thing is that once I run it, the first time it calculates everything runs flawlessly. The problem is when I try to run it a second time in the same program run, it gets an error of a stack overflow.

Comment: @tomassino No, thats the issue  I think

Comment: Make sure all the parameters in the parameter list are the same the first and 2nd time you run the code.  Not sure if the issue is the parameters not being initialize or the data you are parsing is different that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it ok that code that goes after the while loop will be executed multiple times (as many as your recursion level)? 
 Also `path.Reverse()` will be called multiple times, which is something I am not sure you really want.
To prevent that code from executing, you can do something like this:

```
if (!stop)
{
     stop = true;
     path.Add(end);
     path.Add(start);
     path.Reverse();
     arraydeNodes = path.ToArray();
}

return arraydeNodes;
```

I've played with it a little bit and I've modified your code. 
Try this:

```
private Node[] checkTheOtherDude(Node start, Node endpadre, Node end, Node previousNodeTemp)
{
    if (endpadre == null)
    {
        path.Add(end);
        path.Add(start);
        path.Reverse();
        arraydeNodes = path.ToArray();
        return arraydeNodes;   
    }
    else if (!Physics.Linecast(end.transform.position, endpadre.transform.position)) // end y endpadre se ven?
    {
        previousNode = endpadre;
        Node newParent = endpadre.padre;

        return checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, end, previousNode); // chequear n y n padre padre

    }
    else
    {
        //previousNode = endpadre;
        path.Add(end);
        path.Add(previousNode);
        end = endpadre;
        Node newParent = end.padre;
        return checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, endpadre, previousNode);
    }                   
}
```

Try to run this with test data (only few nodes). Then check the path after first click and then debug the second click. You should be able to see the problem point. Maybe there is infinite recursion (cycle in node parenthesis)

Comment: Every time I click, the code runs and generates a path. The first click works great, the second click (during the same program run) throws a stack overflow error.

Comment: still the same, i'm starting to think the problem might come from another place in the code, even though the error says its in those lines.

Comment: Try to run this with test data (only few nodes). Then check the path after first click and then debug the second click. You should be able to see the problem point. Maybe there is `infinite recursion` (cycle in node parenthesis)

Comment: I managed to solve it, it was actually another thing, check my edited post above. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Well, I actually did that haha, it was exactly what you were talking about.

Comment: Ok, I will add that comment to my answer and you may mark it as a correnct answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes just change these 2 lines

```
checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, end, previousNode);
checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, endpadre, previousNode);
```

to

```
return checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, end, previousNode);
return checkTheOtherDude(start, newParent, endpadre, previousNode);
```

these will make it return all the way up

Comment: Every time I click, the code runs and generates a path. The first click works great, the second click (during the same program run) throws a stack overflow error.

Comment: @JackBauer You shouldn't be having your recursive methods cause side effects.  That's your main problem here.  Your recursive methods should compute a value and return it, taking in any data they need as parameters and returning all of their computations as a return value.  Mutating state in the process creates a giant mess, as you are seeing.